# Cannot access request attribute nor parameter with Thymeleaf in Servlet app

Tags: java, servlets, thymeleaf

First of all, is it possible at all to use Thymeleaf template engine in servlet app? If not, what else template engine can I use instead of JSP?

If it is possible, here is my problem: 
I can't access request attribute nor parameter through `th:text`. Error: `can't resolve 'name_of_attr/param'`.

Now to the details.

I created a very simple servlet app with one servlet and one HTML page. 
When I launch the app, my `HomeServlet` adds an attribute to the request. Then the servlet using `RequestDispatcher` forwards my request to `home.html` page. As you can see in the code below, I added `?test=param` to the link, so now we have a parameter too.

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    req.setAttribute("test", "test attribute");
    req.getRequestDispatcher("/home.html?test=param").forward(req, resp);
}
```

Now, in `home.html` I'm trying to access these attribute and parameter using `th:text`.

```
<body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <div th:text="${test}">...</div>
    <div th:text="${param.test}">...</div>
</body>
```

Nothing works and I get the error mentioned at the top. Maybe I should use some different Thymeleaf tag...  Please help me out :)

P.S. I added a thymeleaf dependency to my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
  <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Also I added the following line to my `home.html` page: `xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your initial question whether it is possible to use thymeleaf in servlet mechanism, the answer is yes. Please check this [example](https://github.com/nulab/thymeleaf-servlet-example) and [detailed example](https://github.com/jmiguelsamper/thymeleaf3-servlet-helloworld) which both are good starting points for thymeleaf servlet usage.

As you can see from the examples you should set the variables in WebContext as follows:

```
package test;

import com.thymeleafexamples.thymeleaf3.config.TemplateEngineUtil;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.context.WebContext;

@WebServlet("/")
public class IndexServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        TemplateEngine engine = TemplateEngineUtil.getTemplateEngine(request.getServletContext());
        WebContext context = new WebContext(request, response, request.getServletContext());
        context.setVariable("test", "test attribute");
        engine.process("home.html", context, response.getWriter());
    }

}
```